# Passing a subform filter to a subreport

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-reports

Trying to pass a subform filter to a subreport without success.

```
Dim strFilt As String

If Not IsNull(Forms!TblMain2![QryProceduresDone subform].Form.Filter) Then
        strFilt = Forms!TblMain2![QryProceduresDone subform].Form.Filter
        Me![QryProceduresDone subreport].Filter = strFilt
        Me![QryProceduresDone subreport].FilterOn = True
End If
```

I currently pass the form's filter to the main report without problem.

I know I cannot put the above code in the on open event have tried to put it there and in the On Load event but get the error "Object doesn't support this property or method". Error occurs on the line which has Me![QryProceduresDone subreport].Filter = strFilt

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, the Filter property is a string, thus it will never be *Null*.

Second, have in mind, that the opening sequence of a subform/subreport is three fold:

1. subreport (initial)
2. parent report
3. subreport (final)

So, set in a MsgBox or a Debug.Print line in the OnOpen event to watch.

The brute but simple method can be to insert code to ignore the error at the initial opening of the subreport.